# subversion command line check status for needing a checkin?

Tags: batch-file, svn

My goal is to write a script (or code) to programmatically inspect 50 code projects to see which ones need a check-in and then in a second step check in the modified projects with a single check-in message.

I was hoping that the `svn status PATH` command on Windows would return an error code that said 'Working copy is modified - it needs a check-in!" But as far as I can tell from my experiments, the command returns a cmd.exe errorlevel value of 0 regardless of whether the project has been modified or not.

Of course it would be possible to capture and analyze the output of the command (a list of modified/added/deleted files, for example) to determine if the project needed a check-in. But a status code of some kind would be simpler and less work (I think).

Does anyone know how to generate a list of modified working copy folders without analyzing the console output of the command? Maybe there is a way that I do not see. Thank you

Comment: I believe `svn status -q` does not output anything when there is nothing to commit, so `svn status -q | find /V ""` would return an exit code of `0` if something is modified and `1` if not…

Comment: You are correct! I now have a workable status code for a DOS batch file. I also learned that there is a 'find' command on DOS. Thank you.

Comment: I've replaced your DOS term in your question, please do not confuse cmd.exe in the Windows Operating System with the ancient Disk Operating System.

Comment: No problem. thanks